# How to show only one validation error asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

In asp.net web forms project I have two text inputes that are filled with dates. For one of inputs I have several validation rules.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxShowUntil" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"   
    ValidationExpression="^\d{1,2}(\.|\/)\d{1,2}(\.|\/)\d{2,4}$" ControlToValidate="tbxShowUntil">
    Wrong format. Example: 01/30/2013.
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="tbxExpiration"  
    ControlToValidate="tbxShowUntil" Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Date" 
    ErrorMessage="Must be less or equal to Expiration field." >
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Validation should check that 1) date in the input tbxShowUntil is in correct format and 2) date in tbxShowUntil is less or equal to date in input tbxExpiration. 
When I am entering date in tbxShowUntil in the wrong format, for example, 31-07-2014, both validation errors are shown (wrong format ... and must be less or equal...).
How can I show only one error, so if format error fires, it prevents compare error from firing.
Thanks for everyone in advance

Comment: you can set CompareValidator on tbxExpiration with ControlToValidate="tbxExpiration" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ControlToCompare="tbxShowUntil"

Comment: I suppose, in this situation, I will have 2 validation messages near tbxExpiration if I'll make mistake in it's forma. Or isn't it so?